# PHP mistake renders mail() function not functional

Tags: php, email

Possibly this will be obvious for most, but I wasn't able to figure out the mistake; here is a simple HTML form and PHP code to send an email, including the host (domain) the message was sent from:

```
<?php
    $domainName = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ; 
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
        $subject = 'Hello :)' ;
        $message .= 'E-mail: '.$_REQUEST['email']."\n"."\n" ;
        $message .= 'Host: '.$_REQUEST['dname']."\n"."\n" ;
        $message .= 'Name: '.$_REQUEST['name']."\n"."\n" ;
        $message .= 'Price: '.$_REQUEST['price']."\n"."\n" ;
        $message .= 'Message: '.$_REQUEST['message'] ;
        $to = "mail@domain.com" ; //e-mail
        $header = "From:$name <$email>" ;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header );
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $domainName; ?></title>           
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form method="post" id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >

            <label for="dname">Host</label>
            <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value=""/><!-- WORKS -->
            <!-- <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>"/> --> <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/> 

            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""/>

            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value=""/>   

            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" title="Send Message!" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the form works fine, until I am trying to insert the domain into row 25:

```
<input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>"/>
```

this is where the form stops functioning and cannot figure out the mistake. Any help, a short "what was I missing.." ;) will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What does `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` contain?

Comment: What do you mean by the form stops functioning? Does the page not render? Do you get an error? Does the submit button not work?

Comment: Everything looks fine, no error, nothing visible. The $domainName is visible in the <title> and the form also shows the domain name in the "dname" field. Everything seems fine, however, the mail is not sent. No error logs generated.

I also tried: <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?= $domainName ?>"/> the result is the same, the form does not send email. In case you enter something else in the dname field as value, even value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>, it works again. Last, tried replacing SERVER_NAME with HTTP_HOST, the form stops sending email.

Comment: The issue is here: value="**<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>**" and possibly I am not getting something on how to include $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in the form. I've added the non working line in the code inside a comment. Thank you!

Comment: in your version that doesn't work what is the value echoed? <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>"/> - value="what?"

Comment: @DrCord it echoes the correct domain name both in the <title> and the form, until that point everything is OK (strange).

Comment: the tile and form action are different php calls...what does <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> print out?

Comment: Is prints the domain name: http://yatko.com/p/test.php

Comment: have you tried using Pear PHP? http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Comment: I figured it out, was my mistake! Sending <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> (a domain name or URL) via an email with the mail() function (nobody) will trigger a flag on most spam filters. The mail function was working properly, however, when I inserted the domain in the message body, this was caught by the spam filter. Sorry for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The script had no PHP mistake that renders the mail() function non-functional. The problem was including an URL (link) in the message body when using "echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];"

The message will be sent without issues but including a link in the message body will activate the spam filter and the message gets stuck in the spam folder. After the link (host/domain) is removed from the message, the email arrives in the Inbox again. This caused the confusion.